# Add a row in query result if any date is missing between range SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-range

I am new in SQL and I want to add a row in query result between date range if any date is missing between the date range.

Here is my query

```
SELECT CHECKINOUT.USERID, USERINFO.USERID,
        CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) DATE,
        MAX(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) as MAX_TIME,
        MIN(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) as MIN_TIME
        FROM CHECKINOUT
        LEFT JOIN USERINFO
        ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
        WHERE CHECKTIME BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-10'
        GROUP BY CHECKINOUT.USERID,CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE), USERINFO.USERID, USERINFO.NAME
         ORDER by CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE), USERINFO.NAME ASC
```

**Output of this query**

```
USERID  USERID  DATE    MAX_TIME    MIN_TIME
59  59  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
59  59  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
59  59  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
59  59  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
60  60  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
60  60  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
60  60  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
60  60  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
61  61  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
61  61  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
61  61  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
61  61  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
```

**And My expected Output**

```
    USERID  USERID  DATE    MAX_TIME    MIN_TIME
59  59  2/1/2020    NULL    NULL
59  59  2/2/2020    NULL    NULL
59  59  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
59  59  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
59  59  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
59  59  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
59  59  2/8/2020    NULL    NULL
59  59  2/9/2020    NULL    NULL
59  59  2/10/2020   NULL    NULL
60  60  2/1/2020    NULL    NULL
60  60  2/2/2020    NULL    NULL
60  60  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
60  60  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
60  60  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
60  60  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
60  60  2/8/2020    NULL    NULL
60  60  2/9/2020    NULL    NULL
60  60  2/10/2020   NULL    NULL
61  61  2/1/2020    NULL    NULL
61  61  2/2/2020    NULL    NULL
61  61  2/3/2020    4:11:48 PM  8:47:02 AM
61  61  2/4/2020    6:22:38 PM  8:45:50 AM
61  61  2/6/2020    2:33:43 PM  1:57:55 PM
61  61  2/7/2020    4:29:40 PM  8:39:38 AM
61  61  2/8/2020    NULL    NULL
61  61  2/9/2020    NULL    NULL
61  61  2/10/2020   NULL    NULL
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql cannot itself return rows for non existing data, you have to workaround it yourself making it creating those empty rows.

I hade a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825829/return-empty-rows-for-not-existsting-data), you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59827129/3030926) to achieve what you are looking for.

#### TLDR

You basically use a table with enough rows to provide the quantity of empty rows you need (the answer i linked above use `information_schema.columns`) combined with a variable to generate rows with an incrementing value (`m,...,n`), then you can use those rows and those values to generate the missing data you need, like dates for your use case, and in the end join those default-value rows with your real-data rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the list of dates.  You can do this in multiple ways:

- Explicitly.
- Using a numbers/tally/calendar table.
- Using a recursive CTE.

Then use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows that you want.  And finally a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the data you have already calculated.

Here is an example:

```
WITH uc AS (
      SELECT c.USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) as DATE,
             MAX(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) as MAX_TIME,
             MIN(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) as MIN_TIME
      FROM CHECKINOUT c LEFT JOIN
           USERINFO u 
           ON i.USERID = u.USERID
      WHERE c.CHECKTIME BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-10'
      GROUP BY c.USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE), u.USERID, u.NAME
     )
SELECT u.USERID, d.dte, uc.min_time, uc.max_time
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USERID FROM uc) u CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT CAST('2020-02-01' as DATE) as dte UNION ALL
      SELECT CAST('2020-02-02' as DATE) as dte UNION ALL
      . . .
      SELECT CAST('2020-02-10' as DATE) as dte UNION ALL
     ) d LEFT JOIN
     cu
     ON cu.USERID = u.USERID AND cu.DATE = d.dte
ORDER by d.dte, NAME ASC
```

Comment: Can you please write complete query for me. It's difficult for me

Comment: @sunny . . . This answer has the complete query.

Comment: Actually it showing me error 
`Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 13
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 14
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 15
'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: @sunny . . . Use whatever logic is appropriate for your database.  You haven't specified what database you are using.

Comment: I am using MS SQL